# javascript check if a string combination exists

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string

```
"HCPROG_1.25_3.5"
```

And I have another string

```
"HCPROG_3.5_1.25"
```

Is there a way to check both actually are same ?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```js
var str1 = "HCPROG_1.25_3.5"
var str2 = "HCPROG_3.5_1.25"
function magic(s) {
  return s.split('_').sort().join('_');
}
console.log(magic(str1) === magic(str2))
```

What `magic` does is split the string on `_`, sort the resulting array, then join on `_` (the last bit could join on anything to be honest, even nothing)

The resulting string will be identical regardless of the order of the "parts" between `_`