# Calling setInterval function inside a setTimeout method in java-script getting setInterval(...) is not a function error

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have a simple setTimeout function that runs at a specific time and works fine:

```
var now = new Date();
var milliTillExec = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), 0, 0) - now;
if (milliTillExec < 59500) {
    milliTillExec += 59500; 
}
window.setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('at 59:500');
},milliTillExec);
```

trying to add a function that runs every 300 milliseconds after the previous function fired, so I did like this :

```
 function runEvery300Milli(){
    var t = new Date();
    window.setInterval(function(){
        if((t.getMinutes===59 && t.getMilliseconds>499)||(t.getMinutes===0 && t.getMilliseconds<500)){
            console.log(t.getMinutes()+ ":"+t.getSeconds() + ":"+ t.getMilliseconds());
        }
    }, 300)(); 
}
var now = new Date();
var milliTillExec = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), 0, 0) - now;
if (milliTillExec < 59500) {
    milliTillExec += 59500; 
}
window.setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('at 59:500');
    runEvery300Milli();
},milliTillExec);
```

but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: setInterval(...) is not a function
    at runEvery300Milli
```

Comment: your setinterval looks like `setInterval(fn, 300)()` ... since setInterval returns `undefined`, this is what is not a function - setInterval is, but what it returns is not - simply remove the `()` after `, 300)`

Comment: @Nick, I made a window.setInterval , that didn't work either

Comment: @Bravo you should post as answer mate not comment, as comment can vanish later on, :+1:

Comment: @Mostafa what  ***Bravo*** explained in comment is exact reason for error, here's a [`Demo`](https://jsbin.com/hatuvawezi/edit?js,console),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your setinterval looks like

```
setInterval(fn, 300)()
```

... since `setInterval` returns `undefined`, this is what is not a function, and the cause of the error

i.e. setInterval is a function, but what it returns is not - simply remove the `()` after `, 300)`

```
function runEvery300Milli(){
    var t = new Date();
    window.setInterval(function(){
        if((t.getMinutes===59 && t.getMilliseconds>499)||(t.getMinutes===0 && t.getMilliseconds<500)){
            console.log(t.getMinutes()+ ":"+t.getSeconds() + ":"+ t.getMilliseconds());
        }
    }, 300);  // <=== removed trailing ()
}
```

Comment: You can create a running snippet on SO, [`running snippet on SO`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), anyways +1

Comment: @CodeManiac - yes, but why in this case would a running snippet of part of the OP's code help at all? I see no benefit in producing a snippet of code for such a simple error/solution - for example, yesterday I did so, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230832/fetching-lowest-and-highest-time-of-the-day-from-array/58230950#58230950 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229257/javascript-check-if-a-string-combination-exists/58229381#58229381 to show the output was a required - so I'm well aware of the tools available on SO